# How do you implement CSS without to have clear:both on float left and float right

Tags: css, xhtml

How to clear `float:left` & `float:right` on CSS

You may look an example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/A77Ah/)**

The `wrap` id overlap to the `header` & `search`. How to fix it **without** to put the `clear:both`

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, are you saying that you don't want #wrap to surround #header and #search?

Comment: What is your reasoning for not wanting to use `clear:both`?

Comment: @Hristo - he doesn't want to use an extraneous elements.

Comment: too much `div='clear'` will be use on the html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` on #wrap. Since you already have a width it automatically clears in IE.

http://work.arounds.org/clearing-floats/

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A77Ah/5/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to prevent the wrap from overlapping the two divs then:
wrap should have the attribute `overflow: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You can clear floated divs with br clear="all" if you don't like clear:both